# Interface with an event

Tags: c#, events, interface, nullpointerexception

I just need to raise a custom event and I want to implement it.

Here is the interface:

```
public delegate void Back();

interface IGoBack
{
    event Back GoBack;
    void ExecuteGoBack();
}
```

Here is a working implementation:

```
public partial class LiveView : UserControl, IGoBack
{
    public LiveView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event Back GoBack;
    public void ExecuteGoBack()
    {
        GoBack();
    }

    private void btnGoBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteGoBack();
    }
}
```

THIS IS NOT WORKING (NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ON EVENT):

```
    public partial class ViolationsControl : UserControl, IGoBack
{
    public ViolationsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event Back GoBack;

    public void ExecuteGoBack()
    {
        if(GoBack!=null)GoBack();
    }

    private void btnGoBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteGoBack();
    }
}
```

What do you think I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to declare your event with `public event Back GoBack = delegate {};`

Comment: possibly you have an event handler which throws the nullreferenceexception. its not in the code. (or you remove the reference between the check and the event call)

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov I get "Event in interface cannot have initializer" message

Comment: @user1290141 did you put it on the interface? You should use it in the implementation, i.e. in `ViolationsControl` or/and `LiveView`

Comment: @fix_likes_coding Thanks, I would mark this as answer too, if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising an event is usually implemented like this:

```
public void RaiseGoBack()
{
    var handler = GoBack;
    if(handler == null)
        return;
    handler();
}
```

The reason for this implementation is thread-safety. In your code, someone could have detached the last handler *after* the `if` but *before*  you actually invoke it. In this case `GoBack` would be `null` despite your check.
The implementation above solves this problem by taking a "snapshot" of the currently attached handlers and performing the check and invokation on this snapshot.

Having said that, you need to attach a debugger or check the stack trace to verify the exact location of the `NullReferenceException`. The problem I outlined above is a so called race condition. It usually doesn't happen if you are not using multiple threads heavily.
That means that your exception most likely is caused someplace else, most likely in one of the event handlers.

Comment: Yes, but what if it is always null? (this is what happens with my case)

Comment: @user1290141: What is always `null`?

Comment: var handler = GoBack; // GoBack == null

Comment: @user1290141: Obviously, nobody attached a handler to the event.

Comment: I just dont understand why LiveView control works while the other does not.

Comment: @user1290141: It's impossible to answer. Especially with the vague description "doesn't work". The fact that `GoBack` is `null` is perfectly ok. You just have to attach a handler to the event at some place if you want to react to it.